# What is the size of NSDate in objective-c and swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In java long timestamp is as 8 bytes. 
What is the size of NSDate  in objective-c and swift ?

Comment: convert date to nsdata.than print data.length you got size of nsdate

Comment: Why do you think that would be useful information to have? What are you trying to do with an `NSDate` that you think you require its size?

Comment: In Objective-C like java we also have `NSTimeInterval` which is `double`. `NSDate` is a class not a primitive type.

Comment: An NSDate is an object, so it could change in size from release to release.  If you want to do something portable or store the date in an external system, use `NSTimeInterval` which is a double

Comment: @InderKumarRathore  what is the size of NSTimeInterval ? I need it because I'm considering 8 bytes for timestamp on server side. I've created 28 bytes structure for (8 bytes timestamp + 20 bytes data)

Comment: @VishveshPhadnis `NSTimeInterval` which is `double` is 8 byte long

Comment: @VishveshPhadnis Unless your server is also written in Swift/Objective-C, just knowing the size of the timestamp is insufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS data type size are respectively.

**Integer data types in OS X and iOS:**

[image]

**Floating-point data types in OS X and iOS:**

[image]

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Major64-BitChanges/Major64-BitChanges.html).

While you are asking the size of [`NSDate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdate), its a class not a primitive data type where you can create its object to access its member function and variables. When an object is created the memory is allocated *in HEAP*.

You can use `sizeof()` method in both `Swift` and `Objective c` to get the size of any data type.

Comment: In Swift 5: `MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: Date())` (is 8)

Comment: @JordanH, thanks for your update and your edit is much more appreciable in this.

Answer (score 0):

You should reword your question to clarify what you're actually trying to do.  The size of a time stamp on any platform is irrelevant to the question of storing the time stamp on the server.  Storing the time stamp as raw bytes means it's not portable between devices and/or platforms.  Better to encode the time stamp as a date string and send that to the server for storage.

How the server stored it is another, much broader question, but the basic options are as a string or in some internal format to be converted to/from a string as needed, depends a lot on what you're going to actually do with it on the server.

While we're at it, make sure that you take time zone into account, or, better yet, always use UTC for time stamps.